# Polylang non translatable custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, plugin-polylang

Polylang [plugin documentation](https://polylang.pro/doc/synchronize-metadatas-between-translations/) talks about **non translatable custom taxonomy**. I'm using the plugin Media Libray Assistant, which creates a custom media taxonomy named "attachment category". I woud like the terms of such taxonomy to be non translatable, but by default they are.

Is it possible to tell to Polylang (maybe programmatically) that a certain taxonomy does not need a language specification?

Thanks in advance for your attention.

Comment: when you go in the backend "Languages" -> "Settings", you can choose toxonomies in "Custom post types and Taxonomies". it's this setting you was searching for ?

Comment: @mmm Unfortunately for some reason (a bug?) the "attachment category" taxonomy created by plugin Media Library Assistant is not listed there, that also why I asked help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the plugin **Media Library Assistant** is deliberately setting its custom taxonomy `category_attachment` as translatable by means of configuration file `wpml-config.xml`. Therefore changing the line

```
<taxonomy translate="1">attachment_category</taxonomy>
```

to

```
<taxonomy translate="0">attachment_category</taxonomy>
```

should do the trick. However I did not try myself because I'm not sure of what happens to existing taxonomy terms having a language specification.